# Get Item when scroll in horizontal recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a horizontal Recyclerview with 2 elements

I would like to call a function to load into a data list when I scroll through the elements of the recyclerview.

I would like to load the data of the item located in the center of the screen / Recyclerview

I am trying with `onScrolled` but I cannot figure out when in the Recyclerview I change the item

the elements could perhaps become even more than 2 (for example 6) so if it were possible I would like a function that is not necessarily only for 2 elements

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
     android:id="@+id/list_compte"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
     android:divider="@drawable/rectangle_border_bottom"
     android:paddingLeft="110dp"
     android:paddingRight="110dp"
     android:clipToPadding="false"
     android:dividerHeight="1dp"
     android:isScrollContainer="false"
     android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
     android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

[image]

[image]

it's possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. There is a good tutorial [here](https://medium.com/over-engineering/detecting-snap-changes-with-androids-recyclerview-snaphelper-9e9f5e95c424) by **Nick Rout** which perfectly describes your case.